# Binding partial view to razor page model

Tags: asp.net-core, binding, razor-pages, partial-views, httpcontext

I have a ASP.NET Core Web Application, using RazorPages.
I'm using a partial view for searching for a person. This partial view model (base PageModel) has a constructor with an interface to supply a repository (using DI). This partial view model also has a field for binding the selected persons id.

I use this partial view in a RazorPage, where I want to know the selected persons id. So this RazorPage has a PageModel, with a property being the PageModel for the partial view.

Like this:

```
public class _PartialPageModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly IRepository repository;
    [BindProperty]
    public int SelectedPersonId {get; set;}
    public List<SelectListItem> SearchValues {get;set;}

    public _PartialPageModel(){}

    public _PartialPageModel(IRepository repository){
         this.repository = repository;
    }

    public void OnGet(){
         //use the repository to fill the SearchValues
    }
}

public class RazorPageModel : PageModel{
    [BindProperty]
    public _PartialPageModel SearchModel {get; set;}
    private readonly IRepository repository;

    public RazorPageModel(IRepository repository){
         this.repository = repository;
    }    

    public void OnGet(){
        SearchModel = new _PartialPageModel(repository);
    }
}

In the Razor Markup page: <partial name="_PartialPage" for="@Model.SearchModel"/>
```

However, this gives me the following error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Could not create an instance of type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext'. Model bound complex types must not be abstract or value types and must have a parameterless constructor. Record types must have a single primary constructor. Alternatively, set the 'HttpContext' property to a non-null value in the 'MyProject.Pages.Shared._PartialPageModel' constructor.

I searched and tries several alternatives, but nothing that does not return an error when posting back to the RazorPageModel.

Comment: Recommend you look at View Components rather than partials if DI is required https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/view-components

Comment: Due to environmental or structural problems, I cannot reproduce your problem based on the code you provided, please provide a [Minimum reproducible unit](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).